# LeetCode is strange

Tags: c

I was solving [LeetCode problem number 1, Two Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/), in C language.

> Given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `target`, return *indices of the two numbers such that they add up to `target`*.
>
> You may assume that each input would have ***exactly* one solution**, and you may not use the *same* element *twice*.

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize)
{
    *returnSize = 2;    /* here */
    int* result = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j ++)
        {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                result[0] = i;
                result[1] = j;

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I changed a value of variable returnSize in the 6th line from the top with comment '/* here */'.
But a strange fact is that even if returnSize is not related with a returned value, if I don't write it or set returnSize as another value aside from 2, I get wrong when I send submit. Why is that?

I asked to ChatGPT but I couldn't get a reason why

Comment: Using pointers this way is a way to emulate *pass by reference* in C (which passes all function arguments by value). The variable `returnSize` is likely pointing to a variable in the calling code, and by assigning to `*returnSize` you modify that original variable. This is actually a very basic C idiom, and one that a decent book or other decent learning resource should have taught you.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained, not requiring off-site links.

Comment: ProTip: around here, ChatGPT is regarded as an unreliable source of technical advice.  If you have the poor sense to ask it a technical question then don't compound the mistake by telling us about that.

Comment: As for your question itself, the answer is presumably because LeetCode chooses to test for that, even though the problem statement does not explicitly require you to do anything with `*returnSize`.  I can imagine technical reasons for such a requirement, but they are all to do with the implementation of LeetCode's automated judge, and therefore speculative.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I guess they're trying to say that they tried doing research before coming here. ChatGPT may not be great, but it's probably no worse than a beginner googling on their own.

Comment: Do not use ChatGPT for this kind of research; it doesn't know what it's actually saying.  It's using statistical relationships between words to generate text that looks like something a human would write, but it doesn't actually *know* anything about programming, law, biology, literary criticism, or anything else.

Comment: It's the length of the returned array, which for this question should always be 2. A different length fails the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The infamous chatbot actually has no difficulty providing a clear, accurate and documented answer to this simple question: "why do I need to set *returnSize to 2 in this code ...".  Of course it can make mistakes but it is up to the user to see if the answer makes sense.

Comment: @HELLOQWORLD1, Tip: free unused memory: `return NULL;` --> `free(result); return NULL;`.

Answer (score 1):

Leetcode is not completely clear about how to return arrays in C test programs. They do specify that you should allocate the array, and it is pretty clear from the argument name that you should set the number of elements of the allocated array into `*returnSize`.

For this simple question, the array expected must have a length of `2` so this information is redundant, but consider that it is part of the API.

You should now try and find an algorithm that does not have quadratic complexity.  There are solutions that run in quasi linear time.